# What is the mathematical relation that can best represent the following curve?

Tags: functions, relations, curves

Polynomial functions do not seem to represent the curve well. I do know the curve, but can not arrive at the mathematical relation that represents it.

[image: curve]

Please help me identify the equation for the above curve.

Comment: It sort of looks like the third degree Fourier series approximation of a square wave which would be $\sin(x)+\sin(3x)/3$.

Comment: If you are OK having a piecewise function fitting your curve, then you might be able to fit the curve with a b-spline. The problem is there isn't a good way to choose spline parameters to closely fit the curve, and it is a more complicated process than a single function.

Comment: @CyclotomicField that relation seems bit similar , but vary in the middle part (valley).

Comment: @J. Vo I wish to reproduce the curve for different values, so I am not sure of b-spline would be a good idea if I can not get the relevant mathematical relation.

Comment: Have you tried fitting polynomials in $z=x(40-x)$? Not suggesting this will necessarily work but these are the polynomial functions with the right zeros and symmetry.

Comment: @MarkBennet what you suggested is a parabola. Not sure if this relation will represent well.

Comment: No, I am allowing polynomials in $z$ - which are polynomials in $x$, of course. I may be wrong about my formulation - with a constant term the function $20=0.025 x(40-x)-.0001x^2(40-x)^2 doesn't have the right zeros (but could be scaled to have them) and is starting to have the right shape and another term would get the bulge in the middle. Not sure whether you can tune the constants to get the pattern of gradients you want, though.